# swap imageView and textView in custom listView makes application force close

Tags: android

i just went through this [tutorial to create a custom list with images](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) and it went well,(btw i changed the layout of custom list to a linearLayout here is its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

but what i want is to swap the position of imageView (id=icon) and the textView (id=title),sth like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the problem is that i just get force close on running the app.i know sth is wrong with the convertView in the java code but i dont know what it is.thanks for help

here is my LogCat:

```
04-19 12:06:19.121: I/Process(747): Sending signal. PID: 747 SIG: 9
04-19 12:06:27.611: D/AndroidRuntime(773): Shutting down VM
04-19 12:06:27.621: W/dalvikvm(773): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-19 12:06:27.621: E/AndroidRuntime(773): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.myapp.adapters.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:43)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-19 12:06:27.651: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 12:06:27.671: I/dalvikvm(773): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-19 12:06:28.071: I/dalvikvm(773): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 12:06:29.661: I/Process(773): Sending signal. PID: 773 SIG: 9
```

Comment: was it working properly before layout changing ??

Comment: yes it was working fine.

Comment: then try to change in code, see my answer

Comment: paste the logcat when the application crashes. you haven't received any help yet. so keep the thanks for later. there is nothing wrong in these xml layouts. paste your logcat for better understanding.

Comment: check my updated answer, delete you R.java, file and rebuild project, and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem in not because of layout changing, try to change in your code like below just swap parameters in RowItem class like

```
public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
```

to

```
public RowItem(String title, int imageId, String desc) {
```

and in ImageTextListViewActivity class

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}
```

to

```
rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[i], images[i], descriptions[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}
```

**update :** If you are using eclipse, delete you R.java, rebuild project, run it

Comment: i have done this already but it doesnt work,the layout does not change.

Comment: can you please post you logCat logs, it will to find out the problem

Comment: ok the logcat is included,btw if i used your method for the two textViews it swaps them just fine,but for the imageView it does not work.

Comment: with the update,it worked just as it should have.thank you my friend.really thank you :)